# how to draw good looking polylines in three.js

Tags: three.js

I am developing a CAM application, and my polylines are pretty ugly at some scales: 
[image: ugly polyline]

For now my code is pretty basic as seen here: https://github.com/nraynaud/webgcode/blob/84261babef0d17bf5e49f1b41b2fa289e56a625f/webapp/cnc/threeDView.js

I tried adding a round dot for each line corner (same geometry used by a particle system whose material was a shader creating round dots of the same diameter as the line width), it was better albeit not perfect, but it made rotating the view very slugish.

This example uses 1834573 vertices spread in 73 line strips (each time we change color, we start a new line strip).

I have seen people triangulating the polylines and then using a shader on the triangles, but I'm not sure I can reasonably do that in javascript with so many vertices.